# I try strart auditbeat on my local computer through docker. However I get connection refused from elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I start auditbeat
`docker run --cap-add="AUDIT_CONTROL" --cap-add="AUDIT_READ" docker.elastic.co/beats/auditbeat:7.8.1 setup -E setup.kibana.host=localhost:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["127.0.0.1:9300"]`
but get error *Exiting: couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch hosts. Errors: [error connecting to Elasticsearch at http://127.0.0.1:9300: Get http://127.0.0.1:9300: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9300: connect: connection refused]* I try user also localhost in output.elasticsearch.hosts. When I sent request by *curl http://127.0.0.1:9200* I get successful response from elasticsearch.
Also. Elasticsearch is deployed as docker process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the HTTP port 9200 (the same you curl with) not the TCP port 9300

```
-Eoutput.elasticsearch.hosts=["host.docker.internal:9200"] 
                                          ^
                                          |
                                     change this
```

Comment: docker run --cap-add="AUDIT_CONTROL" --cap-add="AUDIT_READ" docker.elastic.co/beats/auditbeat:7.8.1 setup -E setup.kibana.host=localhost:5603 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["localhost:9200"]
Exiting: couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch hosts. Errors: [error connecting to Elasticsearch at http://localhost:9200: Get http://localhost:9200: dial tcp [::1]:9200: connect: cannot assign requested address]

Comment: Can you replace `localhost` with `host.docker.internal`?